# push view controller doesn't work from collection view cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, navigationcontroller

when I try to navigate new view controller the code run but don't do the job

> the code for cell :

```
protocol NavigateViewControllerDelegate {
    func navigate(destination : String)
}

class LoginCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    var delegate : NavigateViewControllerDelegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews () {
        ...
        loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(login), for: .touchUpInside)
        ...
    }

    @objc func login(){
        ...
        self.delegate = ViewController() as NavigateViewControllerDelegate
        self.delegate.navigate(destination: "MainMenu")
        ...
    }
}
```

and in the view controller :

```
class ViewController : UICollectionViewController,NavigateViewControllerDelegate {
    ...
    func navigate(destination: String){
        print("navigate to main menu")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MainMenuVC(), animated: true)
    }
}
```

the code run and the print instruction done and print "navigate to main menu" in consul but the app didn't navigate Main menu view controller

Comment: is MainMenuVC in storyboard, if it is in storyboard then use have to use the id that you have given to your view controller

Comment: let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourViewControllerIdentifier") as MainMenuVC
                                                                                                                        ,then push mainViewController

Comment: thank you for your answers .. but I build this app fully programmatically and don't use storyboard

Comment: please check if your navigationController is nil or not

Comment: your `ViewController` instance is not even presented at the first place.